# Get dom xml item as string and use as array

Tags: android, xml, arrays, parsing, dom

I searched the net for hours, but I'm stuck.

I used a tutorial for parsing xml, i came to the conclusion it would be best for me to use the DOM xml parser.
Mainly cause the content i parse contains only 30 items.

the xml looks as folowing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sliderlist>
<item>
<urlslide>http://www.google.com</urlslide>
</item>
<item>
<urlslide>http://www.stackoverflow.com</urlslide>
</item>
</sliderlist>
```

The DOM parser (most from a tutorial):

```
TextView urlslide[];


        try {

            URL url = new URL("http://www.mydomain.com/my.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

            /** Assign textview array lenght by arraylist size */
            urlslide = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];


            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

                Node node = nodeList.item(i);

                urlslide[i] = new TextView(this);


                Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
                NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("urlslide");
                Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
                nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();
                urlslide[i].setText(((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue());


                //layout.addView(urlslide[i]);


            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
        }
```

And then the part where i need the parsed content fill me array (what now uses the xml inside the values/res folder):

```
        mTimer=new CountDownTimer(15000, 1000) {

    String[] myArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.testArray);
    //String[] myArray={"http://www.upc.nl/","http://www.google.com","http://www.flyerwall.nl"};    
     //<- String should be read from landingpage.


        int currentIndex=0; 
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             //if (currentIndex<myArray.length) {
                //number.setText("seconds remaining: " +  millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                //currentIndex++;
             //}
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            if (currentIndex<myArray.length) {
                //number.setText("done!");
                mWebView.loadUrl(myArray[currentIndex]);
                currentIndex++;
            } else {
                currentIndex=0;//reset current url to 0
                if (currentIndex<myArray.length)
                //number.setText("done!");
                mWebView.loadUrl(myArray[currentIndex]);
                currentIndex++;
                mTimer.start(); //activate the loop
            }

                mTimer.start();//first time start

        }
     };
```

I went to so much sample codes i that i not got a clue anymore,but my guts say it should be so simple to complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i figured it out:

```
try {

    URL url = new URL("http://www.mydomain.com/my.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

    final List<String> urlList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

    Node node = nodeList.item(i);



    Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
    NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("urlslide");
    Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
    nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();

    urlList.add(((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue());


    }


    mTimer=new CountDownTimer(15000, 1000) {

    Object[] myArray = urlList.toArray();
    .........more code


    };//CountDownTimer ENDS
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("XML Pasing Exception = " + e);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In stead of trying to both parse the XML and build the UI elements in a single run, you should split this into separate steps. Not only because that will simplify your problem (divide & conquer), but also because you'll want to do the netwerk request and parsing of the XML document in a background thread, while all the UI stuff should be done on the app's main (UI) thread.

Unfortunately, it's not completely clear to me what specific step you're having trouble with. If it's gathering the actual data from the XML document, you should breakpoint your code and step through it one step at a time to see where exactly you're running into problems. I do see some opportunities to simplify this step though.

For example: in stead of getting a list of `<item>...</item>` elements, simply get the `<urlslide>...</urlslide>` elements that you're interested in.

```
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("urlslide");
List<String> urlList = new ArrayList<String>();

// iterating over nodes omitted... simply add the value of each node to the list
urlList.add(nodeList.item(i).getValue());
```

That should give you a `NodeList` containing only the 'urlslide' elements. I assume you'll want to end up with a list of urls, so it may be an idea to create e.g. an `List<String>` to  populate with the node's values. As said, you don't want to execute any potentially long running tasks on the main thread, since that will block user interaction and quite likely result in the infamous Android Not Responding (ANR) message. Hence, I suggest you wrap this logic inside something like an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Now that you have the urls, all that remains is show them as a list to the user. If this is indeed what you're after, the [`ListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) widget is a perfect match. I would strongly recommend against creating a separate `TextView` for every url, as your code currently shows. The nice thing about using an `AsyncTask` is that it will automatically call `onPostExecute(...)` once the background work has finished. That is exactly the correct point in time to populate the `ListView` with the parsed data.

There are numerous examples (both here on SO as well as in the API documentation) that can show you how to use an `AsyncTask`, `ListView` etc. If you need any more help, please be as specific as possible about what you're having trouble with.

Comment: Thank you for your help MH, the urls will not be shown to the user as a list or textview.The urls are called one by one by the webview.Therefore is the CountDownTimer() , below i iterate over the array result.So each 15 seconds a new url will be loaded.I now i used a bunch of code that is wrong for my case.But i really tried to find as much possible examples to suit my needs.

Comment: i updated the questions code so you can see what happens after i start the CountDownTimer(), in the meanwhile i working on http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/ , with it i followed your guidiance to show me a listview of the urls in the xml file.But even with this tutorial what covers most of your advice i mis the expertise to get the xml items content into String[] myArray. I excluded the singlelistview parts completely from this tutorial, and also sticked to get the full listing directly from the <item> tag.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass your document into this function instead

```
private List<string> getSlidesFromDocument(Document doc)
{
    NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("urlslide");
    List<String> slides = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(Node node : nodelist) slides.add(node.getValue());

    return slides;
}
```